# Image resize tool with “auto-center” feature

Tags: image-editing

Does anybody know of a tool that can resize an image and automatically center it on it's new dimension?

Example, I have a 200x300 image, I wanted to resize it to 300x300 putting whitespace of 50px on both the right and left sides.

I'm using FastStone Photo Resizer, it works as I wanted including resizing multiple folders at once but it doesn't have that "auto-center" capability.

Comment: What OS are you on, that may be helpful to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that (and much more) with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#space_fill). With ImageMagick installed, type this on your command line / shell (replace arguments to your need):

```
 convert input.jpg -resize 80x80 -size 80x80 \
    xc:blue +swap -gravity center -composite output.jpg
```

This resizes the image to fit within a "canvas" of 80x80 pixels, centers the image and fills the background blue (blue was only chosen as an example).

ImageMagick is [available](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) for several (most?) OSes.

---

#### Folder processing

If you're working in Unix-like environment (Linux, BSD etc - even Mac), you can execute the aforementioned command through `find`, which enables you to process folders etc:

```
find /path/to/my/folder -iname "*.jpg" -exec \
    convert {} -resize 80x80 -size 80x80 \
    xc:blue +swap -gravity center -composite {}_resized.jpg \;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [a commandline tool](http://bummisoft.de/download/bumscaleimage.zip) primary intended on batchjobs for complete folders.

```
scaling images
bumscaleimage [sourcefile] [destfile] [width] [height] [quality] [withoutBorders] [backgroundcolor]
 [sourcefile]   JPG oder Bitamp
 [destfile]     JPG oder Bitamp (Pfad muss nicht existieren)
 [width] in pixels
 [height] in pixels
 [quality] optional default=92 for jpg
 [withoutBorders] optional default=1 0 for borders
    without borders means set possibly only high OR width will be reached
 [backgroundcolor] optional default=$ffffff im angegebenen Format

[sourcefile] also can be used with folder\*.ext , destination than has to be a folder


example
C:\Bilder\Noemi\DSCF0001.JPG C:\test.jpg 100 100 92 0 $ff0000
C:\Bilder\Noemi\*.JPG C:\Zielverzeichnis 100 100 92 0 $ff0000

Freeware for non comercial use
```

Answer (score 0):

CropSize may be an option, it has this feature and many more...
http://forge.zeunic.com/development/2013/cropsize-bulk-image-resize-and-cropping

Comment: Can you include some of the details from that post in your answer? Just providing links is discouraged, see the [FAQ](www.superuser.com/faq).