# Way to auto resize photos before uploaded to cloud service?

Tags: automation, android, photos, cloud-storage

I love using auto syncing services to have my photos taken with my smartphone stored on a cloud storage service. One problem though is that the photos are uploaded in high resolution and takes up a lot of space on the drive.

I wonder if any one knows of a service/strategy to have the auto uploaded photo resized to have it occupy less space when auto stored? That is, without me having to take the photos with lesser quality, I still want photos taken with the highest quality since I may take a photo I really like.

Comment: I created a tool for this purpose, maybe it's usefull for you
http://superuser.com/questions/511053/image-resize-tool-with-auto-center-feature/511055#511055

Comment: @bummi oh that's great! I'll have a look at it!